# Help tranformation of random variables?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, transformation

Let $X$ have the p.d.f $f(x)= \frac{x^2}9$ , $0 < x < 3$, $0$ otherwise, find the pdf of $Y = X^3$

I have this exercise, but I do not know how to start, how do I know if it is a one to one transformation?

Once I have the inverse, how do I obtain the jacobian of the inverse of Y? I am lost help

Comment: The Jacobian method (probably the most direct one): $y=x^3$ yields $dy=3x^2dx$ hence $$f_Y(y)=f_X(x)\frac1{3x^2}=\frac{x^2}9\frac1{3x^2}=\frac1{27},$$ which signals that $Y$ is uniform on $(0,27)$.

Comment: @Did do you know a good tutorial about the jacobian method?, I thought the first step was the inverse funtion of y= x^3

Comment: In theory yes, one should invert $y=f(x)$, but in practice this is rarely so. The general formula is based on the simple following facts: $$y=f(x)\implies dy=f'(x)dx\implies f_Y(y)dy=f_X(x)dx=f_X(x)\frac{dy}{f'(x)}=f_X(f^{-1}(y))\frac{dy}{f'(f^{-1}(y))}.$$ The last formula is actually never useful, one can stay with the pair of identities $$y=f(x)\qquad f_Y(y)dy=f_X(x)\frac{dy}{f'(x)}.$$

Comment: ... More than that, very often simplifications occur in the ratio $f_X(x)/f'(x)$, which make the computation of the inverse $x=f^{-1}(y)$ unnecessary. In the present case, $f(x)=x^3$ and $f_X(x)=x^2/9$ hence $$\frac{f_X(x)}{f'(x)}=\frac{x^2/9}{3x^2}=\frac1{27},$$ and we never used $f^{-1}$ (not that $f^{-1}$ was difficult to write down in this specific case, but yet). Try it on specific examples and you will see...

Comment: ... The strange method that deduces $F_X$ from $f_X$ (one integration), then $F_Y$ from $F_X$ (one inversion of a function), then $f_Y$ from $f_X$ (one differentiation) amounts to go from Toronto to Moscow to Johannesburg to  Chicago instead of flying directly from Toronto to Chicago. Its prevalence on the site is probably caused by its (unfortunate) prevalence in some (but not all) curricula (but I am no expert to know this with certainty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cdf of $Y$ is

$$F_Y(y)=P(Y<y)=P(X^3<y)=P(X<\sqrt[3]y)=
\begin{cases}
0,&\text{ if } y<0\\
\int_0^{\sqrt[3]y}\frac{x^2}{9} \ dx&\text{ if } 0\le y \le 27 \\
1&\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$

Between $0$ and $27$

$$F_Y(y)=\int_0^{\sqrt[3]y}\frac{x^2}{9} \ dx=\frac1{27}\left[x^3\right]_0^{\sqrt[3]y}=\frac1{27}y.$$

It follows that $Y$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,27]$.

Comment: The CDF is usually the easiest way to go when transforming random variables (+1)

Comment: Thanks for answering can you explain more about that tecnique I did not know about it, do you know a good tutorial about this?

Comment: @clauch: As robjohn noted the cdf is usually the easiest way to calculate. Especially if the function is monotonous (so you can take the inverse without separating different cases. Here the function was $x^3$ which is monotonous over $[0,3]$.) Having taken the inverse we got back to the original distribution. In our case an easy integral gave the solution. The last step (which I skipped) was the differentiation of the cdf to get the pdf. This example and the solution is a good tutorial. You can try to apply the method in the case of other examples.

Comment: This is following the three-steps path $f_X\to F_X\to F_Y\to f_Y$. One might prefer to follow the one-step path $f_X\to f_Y$ (which, in the present case, seems at least as *easy* to follow).

Comment: I always use the $f_X\rightarrow F_X\rightarrow F_Y \rightarrow f_Y$ method because I cannot memorize the formula behind the $f_X \rightarrow f_Y$ method. If I want to use it I have to derive the formula again and again which takes more time in my case than doing the "détour".

Comment: what are the step for using this tecnique? I do not understand the notation fx

Comment: @clauch: Step1: Write up $F_Y$: $F_Y(y)=P(f(X)<y)$. If you can invert $f$ then  consider (Step 2.) that $\{f(X)<y\}=\{f^{-1}(f(X))<f^{-1}(y)\}=\{X<f^{-1}(y)\}$. Step 3. Because of Step 2. $F_Y(y)=P(X<f^{-1}(y))=F_X(f^{-1}(y))$. Step 4. differentiate  $F_X(f^{-1}(y))$ with respect to $y$. This gives $f_Y$.

Comment: @clauch: Note that at step 2. increasing of $f$ was assumed! If $f$ is decreasing then the inequality flips.

Comment: thanks for answering what other techniques can I use in this case?

Comment: @clauch: I've found this little tutorial for you: http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pettit/MTH5122/chapter2.pdf

Comment: @zoli thank you for all

Comment: @zoli Here is a mnemonic for you: $$y=f(x)\implies dy=f'(x)dx\implies f_Y(y)dy=f_X(x)dx=f_X(x)\frac{dy}{f'(x)}=f_X(f^{-1}(y))\frac{dy}{f'(f^{-1}(y))}.$$ The last formula is actually not useful, one can stay with the pair of identities $$y=f(x)\qquad f_Y(y)dy=f_X(x)\frac{dy}{f'(x)}.$$

Comment: @Did: Thank you. I will use this mnemonic. But, are you sure that at a certain level the best method of explaining something is that you refer to a formula probably not yet understood by the one who asks the question.

Comment: Ahh... you are changing your argument now. OK, let us have a look at this one: why is it that you assume the direct method (not "formula") is less "understood by the one who asks the question" than the indirect approach? Apparently *this OP* knows neither one nor the other method hence we have a unique chance to make them start with the better one.

Comment: @Did: With all due respect (I mean that! mostly on reputation basis) I did not change my argument. I added an argument. Since I always have to rethink the direct formula, I cannot imagine the direct answer without writing down the argumentation behind. I find it easier and more educative to use the indirect method. I cannot say more about this matter.

Comment: @zoli Zeroth argument: "easiest way to calculate". Probably we can forget this one since the computations needed in the direct method are a strict subset of the ones needed in the indirect one. First argument: "cannot memorize the formula". Cannot argue with that one, although I would be curious to understand why the inability to memorize. Second argument: "formula probably not yet understood by the one who asks the question". Note that second argument $\ne$ first argument, since ability to memorize $\ne$ understanding. (Suggestion: replace respect for rep (absurd) by respect for logic... :-))